# sql server disk I/o question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, hardware

I have a question on disks.
How much I/O can a normal disk and a SAN disk can handle?
I have heard about SAN disks should be able to handle upto 200-300 mb/sec, how much does a normal disk can handle or do we need to decide this based on baseline values?

I wanted to know this because while troubleshooting sql server I/O issues , I want to isolate if SQL Server is posting too much of that a Disk is not able to handle that much load or a disk (I/O path) itself is bad so that I an engage storage team.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have not read this whitepaper, I strongly suggest that you do -- [WHITEPAPER - SQL Server I/O Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlblog/archive/2006/09/20/whitepaper-sql-server-i-o-basics.aspx). It's on 2000/2005 but it can be applied for 2008 R2.

Comment: Also, an observation is that some I/O issues can be improved by adding memory to the server so that more data can be kept in cache.

Answer (score 1):

> How much I/O can a normal disk and a SAN disk can handle?

You have to read the manual to find out or you can do a stress test using [SQLIO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20163) or [SQLIOSim](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231619). Brent has a good article on : [SQLIO Tutorial: How to Test Disk Performance](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/09/finding-your-san-bottlenecks-with-sqlio/)

To see if underlying storage is a problem, you can use `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats`. It will show you where the hot-spots are and you can ask your SAN admin to move them away.

```
 ---Ref: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-to-examine-io-subsystem-latencies-from-within-sql-server/

SELECT
    --virtual file latency
    [ReadLatency] =
        CASE WHEN [num_of_reads] = 0
            THEN 0 ELSE ([io_stall_read_ms] / [num_of_reads]) END,
    [WriteLatency] =
        CASE WHEN [num_of_writes] = 0
            THEN 0 ELSE ([io_stall_write_ms] / [num_of_writes]) END,
    [Latency] =
        CASE WHEN ([num_of_reads] = 0 AND [num_of_writes] = 0)
            THEN 0 ELSE ([io_stall] / ([num_of_reads] + [num_of_writes])) END,
    --avg bytes per IOP
    [AvgBPerRead] =
        CASE WHEN [num_of_reads] = 0
            THEN 0 ELSE ([num_of_bytes_read] / [num_of_reads]) END,
    [AvgBPerWrite] =
        CASE WHEN [io_stall_write_ms] = 0
            THEN 0 ELSE ([num_of_bytes_written] / [num_of_writes]) END,
    [AvgBPerTransfer] =
        CASE WHEN ([num_of_reads] = 0 AND [num_of_writes] = 0)
            THEN 0 ELSE
                (([num_of_bytes_read] + [num_of_bytes_written]) /
                ([num_of_reads] + [num_of_writes])) END,
    LEFT ([mf].[physical_name], 2) AS [Drive],
    DB_NAME ([vfs].[database_id]) AS [DB],
    --[vfs].*,
    [mf].[physical_name]
FROM
    sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats (NULL,NULL) AS [vfs]
JOIN sys.master_files AS [mf]
    ON [vfs].[database_id] = [mf].[database_id]
    AND [vfs].[file_id] = [mf].[file_id]
-- WHERE [vfs].[file_id] = 2 -- log files
-- ORDER BY [Latency] DESC
-- ORDER BY [ReadLatency] DESC
ORDER BY [WriteLatency] DESC;
GO
```